# Python 3: How to sum results into a dictionary

Tags: python, string, csv, dictionary, sum

I am writing a code, which would look through bank statements and aggregate expenses/income into the buckets according to the month they fall in. The data is in csv form and is read as string entries. There are 5 columns in the csv file: column 1 is for date, 4 is for expenses and 5 for income.

The code should:

1. Look up the month in the date string from csv.
2. Add expenses/income into the respective dictionaries.

I hit a snag trying to convert expenses (format: "$0.00") into a float and summing them in dictionaries. Anyone can tell me what I can do here?

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import timestring as ts


months= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
expenses = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0, 10:0, 11:0, 12:0}
income = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0, 10:0, 11:0, 12:0}
exp_cat = []
income_cat = []

files =['export.csv', 'export1.csv']

with open("budgetfile.csv","wt") as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as csvfile:
            records = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            print("Processing file {}. \n" .format(file))
            header = next(records)
            for row in records:
                try:
                    expenses[ts.Date(row[0]).month] += float(row[4])
                    income[ts.Date(row[0]).month] += float(row[5])
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    pass
```

Comment: "I hit a snag". Please describe in more detail the problem you have. Does your code throw an error? Which? Where?

Comment: DO NOT use `float` for money. Use `Decimal` and to remove `$`s do this: `decimal.Decimal('$ 33.50'.replace('$', ''))`

Comment: the snag means what I described: cannot sum column 4 into the dictionary, because strings are not converted into digits. and no errors. I am new to programming to bear with me pls...

Comment: I am getting decimal.InvalidOperation was unhandled by user code
Message: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>] error when I try using decimal.Decimal (row[4].replace('$', ' ')). Negative numbers in row[4] are represented by parenthesis. could it be because of that? also can I use the replace method to replace more than one character? How?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import timestring as ts
import decimal
from collections import defaultdict


months= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
expenses = defaultdict(decimal.Decimal)
income = defaultdict(decimal.Decimal)
'''Optional for less imports
expenses = {x:decimal.Decimal() for x in months}
income = {x:decimal.Decimal() for x in months}
'''
exp_cat = []
income_cat = []

files =['export.csv', 'export1.csv']

with open("budgetfile.csv","wt") as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as csvfile:
            records = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            print("Processing file {}. \n" .format(file))
            header = next(records)
            for row in records:
                try:
                    expenses[ts.Date(row[0]).month] += decimal.Decimal(row[4].replace('$', ''))
                    income[ts.Date(row[0]).month] += decimal.Decimal(row[5].replace('$', ''))
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    pass
```

Comment: used the code above and got this error on MS visual studio 2015: "InvalidOperation was unhandled by user code"  [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]. it points to the last parenthesis.

Comment: @Chuck i just submitted a edit for this, give it like 10-20mins for everyone to accept it and you should see it

Comment: @Uzzee less imports are better than more code, someone MUCH smarter than me said: "I HATE code, and i try to delete as much of it as possible" -- paraphrasing. My point is: welcome imports, and try _really_ hard not to write any code yourself. The more code you have the greater the risk of something breaking, imports (specially those from the stdlib) are AMAZING! :P

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Well, yes! But if you can just use a comprehension instead of an import it may actually be shorter (as in this case it is the same). It is also good to learn not to import everything everywhere if you are building with alot of files.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi- I tried to run the code with the above correction. It still throws the same error. I imported decimal and used the part of code marked as optional. it didnt work.  My imports look like this: from decimal import Decimal, DecimalException
from collections import defaultdict

months= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
expenses = defaultdict(Decimal)
income = defaultdict(Decimal)